# Creating a REST Handler for any of Splunk's REST endpoints

Tags: splunk, splunk-sdk

How to create a Persistent(or any for that matter) REST HANDLER for any given(inbuilt) SPLUNK REST API Endpoint? How to use **PersistentServerConnectionApplication** class ?

I have gone through *https://gist.github.com/LukeMurphey/238004c8976804a8e79570d22721fd99* but cant figure out where to start and how to make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a great .conf presentation about REST Handlers by James Ervin from a few years ago, https://conf.splunk.com/files/2016/slides/extending-splunks-rest-api-for-fun-and-profit.pdf

Sample code is available from https://github.com/jrervin/splunk-rest-examples

James' echo example is quite straight forward. Make sure you also pay attention to the additions that are necessary in `web.conf` and `restmap.conf`.

```
import os
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import msvcrt
    # Binary mode is required for persistent mode on Windows.
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stderr.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

from splunk.persistconn.application import PersistentServerConnectionApplication


class EchoHandler(PersistentServerConnectionApplication):
    def __init__(self, command_line, command_arg):
        PersistentServerConnectionApplication.__init__(self)

    def handle(self, in_string):
        return {'payload': in_string,  # Payload of the request.
                'status': 200          # HTTP status code
        }
```

Suggest you just get a copy of his app and deploy it, confirm it all works, then modify if for your particular use-case.